# Regex - Match URL Until

Tags: regex

What is the "best" way to match a URL in a string that has many commas (,,,,,) and may has a seperator coma following by 404 string. After the ,404 string has come, get the string until this part.

Example:

```
http://stackoverflow.com/this,,,can,be,,a,slug,,,0,404
```

or

```
http://stackoverflow.com/this,,,can,be,,a,slug,,,0
```

I must get: `http://stackoverflow.com/this,,,can,be,,a,slug,,,0`

Tried these:

```
^(.*)(\,404)?
[^,404]*
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use positive lookahead:

```
.*(?=,404)
```

or if you want a capture group, use this:

```
(.*)(?=,404)
```

demo here : http://regex101.com/r/lH1vZ3

Comment: What if there is no ,404 string?

Comment: @R.CanserYanbakan Try modify it like this: [^.*?(?=,404|$)](http://regex101.com/r/zL1rX0) ...add start anchor, make quantifier [greedy](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-greed.html) and add OR end-anchor to `(?=,404)`

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that `(.*)` will match everything, including the 404, if you make that last one optional. What you need is a non-greedy `.*`, which will match as little as possible (not as much as possible).
Try this:

```
^(.*?)(,404)?$
```

(I don't think the `,`should be escaped either)

Of course, if you're not sure you're dealing with a correct url, you should replace the `(.*?)` by some pattern that fits your url, and apply the non-greediness (`*?` or `+?`) there.